# Include notes in seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, plot-annotations

I have a barplot that I would like to include a note at the bottom.
The current code is shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

data = {
'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22],
'survey': ['baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline', 'baseline', 'endline'],
'level': ['low', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'medium', 'medium', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'low', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'high', 'high', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'high', 'medium', 'medium', 'low', 'high', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low', 'low']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_N = df.groupby(['level']).count().sort_index(ascending = True).reset_index()
df_N['%'] = 100 * df_N['id'] / df_N['id'].sum()

sns.set_style('white')
ax = sns.barplot(data=df_N, x='level', y='%', ci=None,
                 palette="rainbow")

N = df_N['id'].to_numpy()
N_it = '$\it{N}$'
labels=[f'{np.round(perc,1)}% ({N_it} = {n})' 
        for perc, n in zip(ax.containers[0].datavalues, N)]

ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], labels = labels, fontsize = 10)

sns.despine(ax=ax, left=True)
ax.grid(True, axis='y')
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(100))
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_ylabel('')
ax.margins(y=0.15)  # optionally some more free space at the top
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I would like to include a note based on disaggregation below

```
df_N = df.groupby(['survey', 'level']).count().sort_index(ascending = True).reset_index()
df_N
```

Specifically:

Note: Baseline: high - 6, low - 10, medium - 6
Endline: high - 8, low - 8, medium - 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `text()` from the `seaborn` module:

```
df_N = df.groupby(['survey', 'level']).count().sort_index(ascending = True).reset_index()
u_values = df_N['survey'].unique()
txt = ""
for val in u_values:
    txt += val + ": "
    a = df_N[df_N['survey'] == val][['level','id']].values.flatten().tolist()
    for i, j in enumerate(a):
        if i % 2 == 0:
                txt += str(j) + " - "
        else:
                txt += str(j) + ", "
txt = txt[:-2]
ax.text(-0.4, -5, txt, fontsize=10)
```

This is the result graph that I get:
[image]

**Note**: The code above was added before the `plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0)` line in your code.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking time and suggesting a solution. I am grateful

Answer (score 1):

You can use [annotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ymiv.png) function to position the note below the figure like so:

```
note = "Note: " + ", ".join([f"{row['survey'].capitalize()}: {row['level']} - {row['id']}" for _, row in df_N_disagg.iterrows()])
    
ax.annotate(
    note,
    xy=(-0.1, -0.2),
    xycoords="axes fraction",
    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round,pad=0.3", edgecolor="black", facecolor="aliceblue")
)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for taking time and offering solution. I sincerely appreciate